# How to pass audio buffer to speech to text service using python

Tags: python, speech-to-text, azure-speech

I am using azure speech to text service using python to process bunch of audios. In order to process the audios, These are the steps performed-

1. Download audio from web server to local 'C:/audio' drive.
2. Pass the path of downloaded audio to Speech SDK's - Audioconfig(filename ='C:/audio/my_audio.wav')

Rather than downloading to local machine, I want to get the file from server and pass it directly to speech to text service. For which,

1. I stored the audio in `bytes` form in audio buffer like this- `raw_audio = my_audio_in_bytes # class <'bytes'>`
2. Then, I pass the audiobuffer to AudioConfig(filename = raw_audio)  - **It doesn't works. Because it expects a filepath**

Is there a way to pass audiobuffer to this service?

Configuration python code:

```
speech_config = speechsdk.SpeechConfig(subscription=speech_key, region=service_region)
audio_config = speechsdk.audio.AudioConfig(filename='C:/audios/audio1.wav')
speech_recognizer = speechsdk.SpeechRecognizer(speech_config=speech_config, audio_config=audio_config)
```

Comment: Check the documentation.  The AudioConfig function accepts a `stream` parameter, although I cannot tell you what format it wants.

Comment: Tested with stream as well, the push/pull streams take the raw data but the final transcripts are messy with lot of redundant words. Hence, tried this approach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@user1990, per our discussion [on this GitHub issue](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/cognitive-services-speech-sdk/issues/975), please use [batch transcription](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/speech-service/batch-transcription), as Speech SDK does not directly support recognizing from a WAV file hosted on a web service (you will first need to download it locally).